# How to add Karma Init to project file

Tags: unit-testing, testing, karma-runner

Hi I'm absolutely new to testing and I have no idea how to add karma to your projects using command line. I actually have no idea how to access my projects using command line and then add Karma test runner to it to test the code. Can someone please help me out ? Thanks

Comment: specify some more details. like framework etc.

Comment: Using karma Jasmine framework and the "karma init" command

Comment: Please refer these links: (1) https://karma-runner.github.io/3.0/intro/installation.html (2) https://karma-runner.github.io/3.0/intro/configuration.html